# Mysqld won't start although lower_case_table_names is 0 and match the data dictionnary

Tags: mysql, restore, recovery, disaster-recovery

I copied a mysql 8.0.26 database from a Linux server to my Windows box but mysqld won't start. Either it's this (with lower_case_table_names=1):

```
[ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Or this  (with lower_case_table_names=0):

```
[ERROR] [MY-010158] [Server] The server option 'lower_case_table_names' is configured to use case sensitive table names but the data directory is on a case-insensitive file system which is an unsupported combination. Please consider either using a case sensitive file system for your data directory or switching to a case-insensitive table name mode.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Is this because the Windows fs is case insensitive? How can I run the database on Windows? Or is this another issue? The database crashed on Linux and I try to repair it on Windows.

Comment: Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html , it may have some clues.  Were they both 8.0.26?

Comment: You may have to do a mysqldump and load to transfer between OSs.

Comment: @RickJames: 8.0.26 won't start on my Windows thus I tried it with 8.0.33. The issue is that I only have the copy. I tried it with recovery 1-6 it's not able to start. However someone else recovered the crashed server but with 6% loss. Is this a version issue 8.0.26 vs 8.0.33? I remember to use mysql database binaries in Linux and Windows and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

this is because the Windows fs is case insensitive.

Just confirm that you don't have the same table name with option lower_case_table_names(it happens rarely), and change it to 1 or 2, then you can only start it in windows.

Comment: Please explain your answer for future visitors.